# Would it be better to create an entirely new action in my controller or should I create a new controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically I have an existing CollegeClass Controller that has the default basic RESTful actions like show for showing the webpage for that college class,edit for editing, and update for the post action of editing the page itself.  I need to add an additional **single** "About the class" webpage to this resource which will not add another model.  It will just add another field to the existing CollegeClass table for the html that will present the new page.

Should I create a controlller exclusive to the "About the class"?  Or should I add on into the CollegeClass controller new actions?  Or do I need to nest this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: it sound like static content for the "About the class" webpage. If its realy static, you can make a special controller for static content redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the custom action and just route it inside college routes as

```
resources :colleges do
  member do
    get 'about'
  end
end


CollegeController < ApplicationController
  def about
  end
end
```

Comment: What about the create, edit, and update actions?  The college professor will have the capability to edit the html field for that CollegeClass.  Should I add all of those in there as well?